# Login screen not working when Ethernet cable connected

Tags: ethernet, ubuntu-gnome

I recently update my OS to Ubuntu 18.04. after this update, i restarted my computer. It boots well. Displayed login screen but hanged. I couldn't not login. I removed my Ethernet cable and restarted again. Now it allows me to log in my user. Why login screen doesn't working when Ethernet cable connected?